# React+redux-form - redirect after submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom v4 . How can I **redirect** to the page after form submit success?

I followed that tutorial [LINK](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.11/examples/syncValidation/) . Then I created my own **submit function** :

```
    const submit=({email='',password=''})=>{
  let error={};
  let isError=false;
  if(email.trim()===''){
    error.email='Required';
    isError=true;
  }
  else if(![ 'test@wp.pl' ].includes(email)){
    error.email='User does not exist';
    isError=true;
  }

  if(password.trim()===''){
    error.password='Required';
    isError=true;
  }
  else if(password!=='test'){
    error.password='Wrong password';
    isError=true;
  }
  if(isError){
    throw new SubmissionError(error);
    }
  else{

      //redirect to new page
    }
}
```

In the comment place there should be a redirect funtion, but I don't have idea how to do it. I tried put there :
`<Redirect to="/pageAfterSubmit" push />` but nothing happened.

My browser router in **index.js** looks like this:

```
<BrowserRouter >
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            <Route path="/"  component={LoginForm}></Route>
            <Route path="/markers" component={Markers}></Route>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
          </div>
    </Provider >
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try this: `this.context.route.transitionTo('/pageAfterSubmit')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a state variable `redirectToNewPage` which when true does the redirect. In the `callback` set `redirectToNewPage` equal to true.

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    redirectToNewPage: false
  }

  const submit=({email='',password=''})=>{
     ...
     else{

     //redirect to new page
     this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true })
     }
   }

   render() {

   // The part that makes the redirect happen
   if (this.state.redirectToNewPage) {
     return (
     <Redirect to="/pageAfterSubmit"/>
     )
   }

   return (
     ...
   )  

  }
}
```

Comment: Try the one above. Modified it.